# Получить директорию исполняемого Jar файла

Tags: java

Пытаюсь получить путь вот так:

```
public class MainClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        File f = new File(MainClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI());

        String dir = (f.toString());

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, dir);

    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
}
```

В в IDE всё работает, но после компиляции в jar получаю.

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical
```

Comment: но ваш код не возвращает наименование jar-файла - только путь

Comment: @Nikolay, поправил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно мой метод странный, но он делает всё что мне нужно)

```
File jarDir = new File(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource("MainClass.class").getPath());
System.out.println(jarDir.getAbsolutePath());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static File getJarDir(Class cls) {
    URL url;
    String extURL;

    try {
        url = cls.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
    } catch (SecurityException ex) {
        url = cls.getResource(cls.getSimpleName() + ".class");
    }

    extURL = url.toExternalForm();

    if (extURL.endsWith(".jar"))
        extURL = extURL.substring(0, extURL.lastIndexOf("/"));
    else {
        String suffix = "/" + (cls.getName()).replace(".", "/") + ".class";
        extURL = extURL.replace(suffix, "");
        if (extURL.startsWith("jar:") && extURL.endsWith(".jar!"))
            extURL = extURL.substring(4, extURL.lastIndexOf("/"));
    }

    try {
        url = new URL(extURL);
    } catch (MalformedURLException mux) {}

    try {
        return new File(url.toURI());
    } catch(URISyntaxException ex) {
        return new File(url.getPath());
    }
}
```

[Отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20953376/1911548)

Comment: Спасибо натолкнули на идею!